# Using environment variable for starting external program

Tags: visual-studio-2012, environment-variables

I am building a class library. In order to test it, I have set up Visual Studio to run an external program which uses the class library (`Project Properties\Debug\Start Action\Start external program`).

However, Visual Studio does not accept environment variables as part of the path there. It says:

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target '...' is
>   missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and
>   AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location
>   for the target assembly.

Is there a setting or any other way to allow environment variables?

Comment: I'm curious why you don't just add another project to your solution, which is a "Test app" for the class library. This test app would then be set as the "Startup project" which is run when you start debugging. References are easier to add too, because you can simply add a reference to (the output of) another project directly.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: The test app is a 3rd party product which initializes a database and loads tons of other stuff. It's not so simple to generate all the initialization objects which my class library will receive (god object code smell). The 10 year old API is not designed for testability :-(